# Not showing error message?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using below mention code for login and register.

first it will ask email then it will check database it exist or not, If exist it will ask password else it ask for register.

```
<div class="onepage_login">
<script type="text/javascript">
function emailcheck(email){
document.getElementById("myform").submit();
}

</script>

<?php 
  $email=$_POST['email'];

        if(isset($_POST['email'])){
       $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
        $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
        $customer->loadByEmail($email);
        if ($customer->getId()) { ?>  


            <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
            <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer.form.login.extra')?>
                    <div class="Custom_login">
                        <div class="C_login">
                            <form action="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl();?>customer/account/loginPost/" method="post" id="login-form" class="Custom_checkout">
                                        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
                                        <label><h1>Get started with our login flow</h1></label>
                                         <div class="checkout_login_email">
                                            <input type="text" name="login[username]" placeholder="Your Email ID (username)" value="<?php echo $_POST['email'] ;?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email check_custom_login complete_mail" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" readonly />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="change"><a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage'); ?>"> Change </a></div>
                                            <br/><br/>
                                        <div class="checkout_login_pss">
                                            <input type="password" name="login[password]" placeholder="Password" class="input-text required-entry validate-password check_custom_login_pass" id="pass" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" />
                                        </div>
                                        <br/><br/>
                                        <div class="checkout_login_button">
                                         <button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Login') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span ><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></span></button>                                        
                                        </div>

                                         <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
                            </form>
                        </div>    
                    </div>   
          <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
                var dataForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);
            //]]>
            </script>
    <?php    
        }
        else{
            //echo"not available";
             ?>

            <form action="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl();?>customer/account/createpost"   method="post" name="fom" id="form-validate">
                   <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
                    <div class="Checkout_reg">
                        <ul class="form-list">
                            <div class="customer-regi">
                               <div class="field name-email">
                                    <div class="input-box"> 
                                        <input placeholder="Email Address" onblur="emailcheck(this.value);" type="email" name="email" id="email" class="input-text complete_mail" required value="<?php echo $_POST['email'] ;?>" readonly />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="change"><a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage'); ?>"> Change </a></div>

                                <!-- <div class="field name-firstname">
                                        <div class="input-box">
                                        <input placeholder="Name" id="lastname" name="firstname" value="" title="First Name" maxlength="255" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div> -->
                                <div class="field name-psw">
                                        <div class="input-box">
                                        <input placeholder="Set New Password" type="password" pattern=".{6,20}" required title="Password should atleast 6 characters" name="password" id="password1"  class="input-text required-entry validate-password" required />

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="field name-cnfpsw">
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <input placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" minlength="6" name="confirmation"  id="password2" class="input-text required-entry validate-cpassword" required/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <button type="submit" name="continue" class="button" id="onepage-guest-register-button">
                                        <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?></span></span>
                                    </button>

                        </div>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
            </form>






        <?php }

}
else{?>
<form id="myform" name ="myform" method="POST">
    <label><h1>Get started with our login flow</h1></label>
    <input placeholder="Email Address" type="email" name="email" id= "email" class="input-text check_custom_login" required autocomplete="on"/><br/><br/>   
    <button class="button" name="submit" onclick="emailcheck();"/> <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?></span></span> </button>
</form>

<?php }

?>

</div>
```

But My problem is if i enter wrong password it won't throw any error it again ask a mail how to i fix it ?

Comment: What happen if you move `<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>` outside of the `if` statements?

Comment: No it's same only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>` outside of the if statements, because after you post the 'username/password' $_POST['email']` will be false